# Why setInterval and clearInterval is not working in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS.

I have 2 cards like the below,

```
<div class = "card" id ="c1">
     <div class = "content"> </div>
</div>

<div class = "card" id ="c2">
     <div class = "content"> </div>
</div>
```

The div `content` in the card 1 should display the dynamic value like `Date.now()` and the `content` in card2 should display the static Value.

**JS:**

```
function cardData(card) {
    myCard(card);
}

function allCardData() {
    var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(cards, (card) => {
      cardData(card);
    });
  }

function mockData(card) {
  
   var setInt;

    function caseOne(card, callBackOne) {
      callBackOne(card);
    }

    function caseTwo(card, callBackTwo) {
      callBackTwo(card);
    }
    
    // SetInterval function
    function callBackOne(card) {
      setInt = setInterval(function () {
        var currentDate = Date.now();
        var val = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2);
      }, 1000);
    }
    //clearInterval
    function callBackTwo(card) {
      clearInterval(setInt);
    }
   
   
  switch(card) 
    {
     case "c1":
     return {
       target: card,
       value: caseOne(card, callBackOne)
     }
     case "c2":
     return {
       target: card,
       value: caseTwo(card, callBackTwo)
     }
     }
     }
     
   function Callback(value, callback) {
    callback(value);
    }
 
  function myCard(card) {
    Callback(mockData(card), function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      var target = document.getElementById(data.target);
      var content = target.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
      content.innerHTML = data.value;
    });
  }
 
 
  //Onload function
 window.onload = function () {
 allCardData();
 };
```

I need a **dynamic data every 2S** in **card1** and a `static data Which clears the dynamic value` in **card2.**

**But, it is not working.**

Since, **callback function** expects `return`, When I pass the function `mockData` to the callback. It is not working as expected.

Could someone please help me `to start the dynamic data in card1 and clear the data in card2`.?

Many thanks.

Comment: Well have you tried debugging? You can stop execution of the code at any time with a breakpoint and just look at the variable values. Or put `console.log(card)` in `mockData()` or in `caseOne()` and `caseTwo()` so you see if everything is executed how you expect.

Comment: @Peter Krebs. Yes, I tried debugging. console.log(data) gives a static value 3 for the case 1 and for case 2 the value is undefined.

Comment: Sure what about `console.log(card)` then? Is that correct everywhere? The `clearInterval(setInt)` return value is undefined, no need to save it in a variable. See [clearInterval docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

Comment: console.log(data) in mockData() gives the card Id "c1" and "c2".

Comment: Removed `return` from the clearInterval. But, it didnt work. Could you please help me? @PeterKrebs

Comment: Removing the return was not the solution, I was trying to make you think about what your sourcecode does and analyze yourself... please check answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code does:

- Calling `allCardData()` for `window.onload`
- `allCardData()` calls `cardData()` for each card found with the card's id
- `cardData()` calls `myCard()` in an intermediate step
- `myCard()` makes `Callback` call `mockData()` for the card
- `mockData()` calls `caseOne()` for card c1 and `caseTwo()` for card c2
- `caseOne()` sets a 2 second interval
- `caseTwo()` cancels the interval

There is no time between calling `caseOne()` and `caseTwo()`. They are called after each other with no time in between. This means the timer is cancelled immediately after it is initialized. No time for the 2 second timer to do anything.

Suggested solution to change `caseTwo()` to only clear timer after a certain condition has passed. Otherwise the interval will never start.
You may want to google about [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await), you may need to change your code in other parts:

```js
  async function caseTwo(card) {
    // asynchronously wait, stopping this function until the value is known
    var value = await getValueTwoFromSomewhere();
    
    clearInterval(setInt);
    return value;
  }
```

Otherwise the code would need to be rewritten to something different.
Maybe you want to rethink your solution and post it again as another question.

Comment: Thank you so much! . I need to know, one thing how setInterval and clearInterval works in the switch case within a function `mockData`. How the `mockdata` can be retrived from the callBack()?  Could you give me some suggestions ?

Comment: Your code tries to be linear, but what you want to do is asynchronous. The callback cannot get the value, because the value is not yet known. You can change your code so `caseOne()` and `caseTwo()` call the callback instead when the value is known.

Comment: Thanks ! But, I didn't get you. Could you please explain in brief.

Comment: I mean give `caseOne()` and `caseTwo()` also the callback function as a parameter and call the callback function in there. This way you can make the callback set the value and stop the timer at the correct time.

Comment: `caseOne()` and  `caseTwo()` are already inside mockData() Which we pass inside the callback like  `Callback(mockData(card), function (data) { });` Do I need to add `caseOne` and `caseTwo()` out of `mockdata()` ?

Comment: If so, Do I need to add the function function Callback(value, callback, callback, callback) {
    callback(value);
    } and pass the `callback` function to  `Callback(mockData(card), caseOne(card), caseTwo(card), function(data) { }` inside myCard() ? Could please help me? Thanks.

Comment: It should suffice if in `mockData` you also set the callback in the switch statement: `... case "c1": return { target: card, value: caseOne(card, callbackOne) }` as an example. Then you can implement `callbackOne` and `callbackTwo` or whatever you name them.

Comment: all the callback's should be inside mockData(). ? If I use ... case "c1": return { target: card, value: caseOne(card, callbackOne) } Do i need to implement  like   Function mockData(card){ var setInt;
   function caseOne(card, callBackOne) {
    callBackOne(card);
   }
 function caseTwo(card, callBackTwo) {
 callBackTwo(card);
  }
   function callBackOne(card) {
    setInt = setInterval(function() {
     var currentDate = Date.now();
      var val = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2);
    }, 1000);
   }function callBackTwo(card) {
      clearInterval(setInt);
   }}

Comment: Kerbs, again It is ok to just pass the mockData() to the callBack function ? Could you please tell me.

Comment: If you try and it works then yes, otherwise no. It is very specific to how you programmed this. It seems you are trying to learn everything in JavaScript at once. You will learn later how to make it more elegant, for now you can just make it work. Just use breakpoints and/or `console.log` calls to understand what happens in which order.

Comment: @Kerbs,  Yes, I tried all the functions inside the mockData() . But, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kerbs . Not all the functions. After adding the callback for caseOne() and caseTwo(). Thanks for your time.  Do you have a developer?

Comment: Well, *you* said all the functions. You will need to share your updated code. Either way it is more complicated than I can explain to you. I don't know anyone, no. You can search the internet for developers for hire.

Comment: @Kerbs, updated the code with the callbacks in the switch case. console.log inside myCard() gives the value as `undefined` for both the cases. Could you please help? Many thanks.

Comment: You misunderstood. You don't call the callback immediately. What is the use of that. You have a problem where you get the value later than you call the callback. Call it **after** you have the value to set the value. This would have to be rewritten completely if you don't understand. I thought I would help debugging but it turns out you are trying random things. Please just find a developer, it will be easier.

Comment: @Krebs, Thanks..So, you mean once the caseOne and caseTwo  gets the value. I need to pass the value in the callback.. Is this correct?

Comment: Sure no problem. Yes, for example you can choose what to do with the value in the callback - setting the `innerHTML` or `innerText`, for example.

Comment: @Krebs. Thank you so much. But, caseOne and caseTwo didn't work properly. They didnt give the desired response. Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: What I'm saying is you can make `caseOne` and `caseTwo` just do what you need to get the value and *at the end* you call the callback. A callback does not have to be called immediately.